# Graph with cropped letters

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks

If I compile this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,every axis/.append style={
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=middle,
  ticks=none}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-.2,xmax=2.75,ymin=-.2,ymax=2.25]
      \plot[thick,samples=100,domain=.5:2.5] {1/x};
      \coordinate (a1) at (.8,0);
      \coordinate (a2) at (0,1.25);
      \coordinate (b1) at (2,0);
      \coordinate (b2) at (0,.5);
      \node[below] at (a1) {\footnotesize$a$};
      \node[below] at (b1) {\footnotesize$b$};
      \node[left] at (a2) {\footnotesize$1/a$};
      \node[left] at (b2) {\footnotesize$1/b$};
      \draw[thin,dashed](a1)--(a1|-a2)--(a2);
      \draw[thin,dashed](b1)--(b1|-b2)--(b2);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

then what I get is this:

[image]

As you can see, part of the text to the left of the vertical axis was cropped. I can easily fix this by replacing `xmin=-.2` with `xmin=-.25`, but what should I do if I do not want to have my text cropped while keeping `xmin=-.2`?

Comment: Try add `clip=false` to your  `\pgfplotsset` or make `xmin` more negative (for example `xmin=-2.5`.

Comment: I explicitly wrote in my question that I knew that making `xmin=-2.5` would work. But your other suggestion works. Thank you. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just move the nodes out of the axis environment. (Using `clip=false` can have undesired side effects such as overshooting plots.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,every axis/.append style={
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=middle,
  ticks=none}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-.2,xmax=2.75,ymin=-.2,ymax=2.25]
      \plot[thick,samples=100,domain=.5:2.5] {1/x};
      \coordinate (a1) at (.8,0);
      \coordinate (a2) at (0,1.25);
      \coordinate (b1) at (2,0);
      \coordinate (b2) at (0,.5);
      \draw[thin,dashed](a1)--(a1|-a2)--(a2);
      \draw[thin,dashed](b1)--(b1|-b2)--(b2);
    \end{axis}
    \node[below] at (a1) {\footnotesize$a$};
    \node[below] at (b1) {\footnotesize$b$};
    \node[left] at (a2) {\footnotesize$1/a$};
    \node[left] at (b2) {\footnotesize$1/b$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are various other options, e.g. adding these nodes as extra ticks, which also do not get clipped.

Comment: Didn't know that the `axis` env prevents automatic bbox calculation. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexG The axis does not prevent automatic bounding box computation but it dials the size of the bounding box on the basis of stuff which you add via `pgfplot` means. It does not take into account stuff that you add via plain Ti*k*Z methods. And it clips the stuff accordingly, which is in general a good thing. Yet you can access coordinates set inside the axis in the ambient `tikzpicture`, which does not clip (by default).

Comment: Clever trick with coordinates defined inside `axis`.

Comment: @AlexG This trick has been used at various places. In general, symbolic coordinates can be accessed from outside, there are exceptions, though, e.g. in the context of nonlinear transformation, where you need to work harder.

Answer (score 12):

I see that you set `ticks=none`, and then manually added something very much like axis ticks.  If you use PGFPLOTS's own tick-placing system, the tick labels do not get clipped.

In this example, there's a lot of keysetting, but less code once the plot is drawn.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,every axis/.append style={
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=middle,
  xticklabel style={name=xtick \ticknum},
  yticklabel style={name=ytick \ticknum},
}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,xmax=2.5,ymin=0,ymax=2,
        enlargelimits,
        xtick={0.8,2},
        xticklabels={$a$,$b$},
        ytick={0.5,1.25},
        yticklabels={$1/a$,$1/b$},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
    ]
      \addplot[thick,samples=100,domain=.5:2.5]  {1/x};
      \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
      \coordinate (a1) at (xtick 0 |- O);
      \coordinate (a2) at (ytick 1 -| O);
      \coordinate (b1) at (xtick 1 |- O);
      \coordinate (b2) at (ytick 0 -| O);
      \draw[thin,dashed](a1)--(a1|-a2)--(a2);
      \draw[thin,dashed](b1)--(b1|-b2)--(b2);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Notes:

- We can see that the y tick labels are automatically not clipped.
- The `xticklabel style` and `yticklabel style` keys give names to the nodes which are the tick labels.  Then we can locate the `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, and `b2` nodes along the axes using those tick labels.
- Rather than enlarge the limits manually by adding or subtracting a bit to each min and max, the `enlargelimits` key does that for us.
- the `typeset ticklabels with strut` makes the baselines of the `a` and `b` tick labels align.  We can shift the x tick labels closer to the x axis with `xticklabel shift={-1.5mm}` or something similar.

Answer (score 11):

Let me convert my comment to an answer. In your case `clip=false` will work just fine:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
    axis lines=middle, % <---
    ticks=none}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style={font=\footnotesize, text height=1.2ex, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-.2,xmax=2.75,
    ymin=-.2,ymax=2.25,
    clip=false] % <---
      \plot[thick,samples=100,domain=.5:2.5] {1/x};
    %
      \coordinate[label=below:$a$] (a1) at (0.8,0);   % <---
      \coordinate[label=below:$b$] (b1) at (2.0,0);   % <---
      \coordinate[label=left:$1/a$] (a2) at (0,1.25); % <---     
      \coordinate[label=left:$1/b$] (b2) at (0,0.5);  % <---
    %
    \draw[very thin, densely dashed]   
        (a1) |- (a2)     (b1) |- (b2);  % <---
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the graph increased in its size? ATM I do not have a place for test your code.

Comment: @manooooh, I  use `standalone` document class. This maybe make some difference in image size in comparison to case, when is used `article`.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't pay attention to your first line of code. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for mentioning this but as soon as someone adds some keys like `ymax` choosing `clip=false` is not a very good option. One might have to adjust the domain by hand, install a filter, or do other things. But I agree of course that in this very case it works.